# Select in ADO (vb6) with a numeric variable

Tags: vb6, ado

Excuse me, occasionally I refer with some problem that maybe it's already been fixed. In any case, I would appreciate a clarification on vs.
I have a TariffeEstere table with the fields country, Min, Max, tariff
from which to extract the rate for the country concerned, depending on whether the value is between a minimum and a maximum and I should return a single record from which to extract its tariff:
The query is:

```
 stsql = "Select * from QPagEstContanti Where country = ' Spain ' 
       and min <= ImpAss and max >= ImpAss"
```

Where ImpAss is a variable of type double.

When I do
    rstariffa.open  ststql,.....
the recodset contains a record if e.g. ImpAss = 160 (i.e. an integer without decimals), and then the query works, but if it contains 21,77 ImpAss (Italian format) does not work anymore and gives me a syntax error.

To verify the contents of the query string (stsql) in fact I find:

```
Select * from QPagEstContanti Where country = 'Spain' and min < = 21,77 and max > = 21,77
```

in practice the bothering and would like a comma decimal, but do not know how do.
I tried to pass even a

```
format (ImpAss, "####0.00"),
```

but the value you found in a stsql is 21,77 always.
How can I fix the problem??

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the underlying language setting in SQL is expecting '.' decimals instead of ',' decimal notation.

To check this out - run the DBCC useroptions command and see what the 'language' value is set to.  If the language is set to English or another '.' decimal notation - it explains why your SQL string is failing with values of double.

If that's the problem, the simplest way to fix it is to insert the following line after your stsql = statement:
  stsql = REPLACE(stsql, ",", ".")

Another way to fix it would be to change the DEFAULT_LANGUAGE for the login using the ALTER LOGIN command (but this changes the setting permanently)

Another way to fix it would be to add this command to the beginning of your stsql, which should change the language for the duration of the rs.Open:
     "SET LANGUAGE Italian;"

Comment: But I use file access .mdb

Comment: Antony, My apologies, since I didn't know it was MS Access.  Try the 1st solution: **stsql = REPLACE(stsql, ",", ".")**.  Ignore the other options

Comment: Timothy, Tanks for all